# asyncio.async(cor()) doesn't work in an async function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I use the following code to suspend a corutine function:

```py
import asyncio

async def hello5():
    print('Hello5 ...')
    # await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print('... 5World!')


# @asyncio.coroutine
# def hello4():
#     print('Hello4 ...')
#     yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
#     # yield from hello5()
#     print('... 4World!')


async def hello4():
    print('Hello4 ...')
    asyncio.async(hello5())
    # yield from hello5()
    print('... 4World!')

loop1 = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop1.run_until_complete(hello4())
loop1.close()
```

However it can't be recognized and has the following error

```
  File "C:\xx\white_board_asyncio.py", line 187
    asyncio.async(hello5())
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I use python 3.6 so async should work, I am wondering why this happens. Can't the asyncio.async be used in an async function? I can use that outside the async function.

The following works well

```py
loop1.run_until_complete(asyncio.async(hello5()))
```

I just wonder why I can't use it in another corutine function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`asyncio.async` was deprecated in 3.5 when `async def` was added. It was removed in 3.7 when `async` became a proper keyword. Use `asyncio.ensure_future` instead.

Comment: Or, [even better](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/477#issuecomment-268709555), `create_task`, which exists as both an event loop method and (as of 3.7) a [top-level function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task).